# Python nested list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, nested

in my code i have created a nested list via list comprehension containing hex numbers. My next step was to calculate the decimal value of these hex numbers.
My last step was removing the () brackets of each element, because my former method created tupels for each list element.
My question here is, can i combine all three steps into one big step and if yes, will it be more efficient in computing ?

My code looks like this:

```
from struct import unpack
from codecs import decode

self.step1 = [[self.inputlist[self.otherlist[i]+k] for i in range(len(self.otherlist))]
        for k in range(asd)]
self.step2 = [[unpack("<B",decode(x,"hex")) for x in y] for y in self.step1]
self.step3 = [[p[0] for p in q] for q in self.step2]
```

this code worked fine (i shortened it and am not showing how self.inputlist,otherlist,asd are defined). I am just curious if i can put self.step1, self.step2,self.step3 into one nested list comprehension.

Comment: You can see it yourself by replacing the `self.step1` in the `self.step2` and replacing it again in `self.step3`

Comment: Even if it gets faster (which I doubt), I don't think it is something you should do because the resulting code will look horrendous.

Comment: i will try that thank you